# Kentico ASPX+Portal templates not registering zones in database

Tags: asp.net, kentico

In Kentico I'm using ASPX+Portal model created a template as a webform on disk with a single widget zone as follows:

```
<asp:Content id="content" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="content">
    <h1>Home: <%= this.PageModel.DisplayTitle %></h1>
    <cms:CMSPagePlaceholder ID="plcZones" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <cms:CMSWebPartZone ID="zoneEditorContent" runat="server" ZoneTitle="Page content" WidgetZoneType="Editor" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </cms:CMSPagePlaceholder>
</asp:Content>
```

I then registered this in Kentico's *Page templates* module.

Pages using this template would now show the zone on the Page tab but wouldn't let me add widgets to it. I could browse the widget library, select a widget, set its properties, save and close the dialogue, but the page would refresh remaining empty.

After some dabbling I discovered that the relevant template record in database table `[dbo].[CMS_PageTemplate]` had its `[PageTemplateWebParts]` property set to the value '`<page />`'.

I discovered that changing this to '`<page><webpartzone id="zoneEditorContent" v="1" widgetzonetype="editor" /></page>`' resolved the problem. I could now add widgets to the zone on the Page tab.

My question is, what am I doing wrong here? I presume I'm not supposed to set this database field manually. Should Kentico be doing this automatically, and if so, what step am I missing to make this happen? I believe I've followed [Kentico documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Adding+portal+engine+functionality+to+ASPX+page+templates) accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. I have to agree this is weird behavior but it is not possible (= does not take any effect) to set *WidgetZoneType* property in markup. You need to set it manually via admin UI (zone properties). If this is issue for you consider to add it to [Kentico`s User voice](http://ideas.kentico.com/forums/239189-kentico-product-ideas).

YMHO I think you are right and it should be at least mentioned in doc that it is not possible to use this property in markup.

EDIT: My bad, please note it is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Setting+up+widget+zones+on+pages), too:

> Changing the WidgetZoneType property directly in layout code does not save the changes in the database. You need to set the Widget zone type property by configuring the zone properties.